# MySQL: Why is UTF-8 called a character set?

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8

UTF-8 is an [encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) used to represent the Unicode [Character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set). Other encodings can also be used to represent this same character set. So why does MySQL erroneously call UTF-8 a character set, instead of rightfully calling it an encoding? I am aware that some people confuse the two terms, but from a large, respected software project I would not expect such confusion.

Example MySQL usage:

```
CREATE TABLE names (name VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8);
```

Comment: Felt like [tilting at windmills](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilting_at_windmills) today?

Comment: @Joe: No, but frustrated at MySQL's UTF-8 lingo. They even call it "utf8" which is [not a valid synonym](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets) for UTF-8. At least once one figures out how they made up their own words and definitions, it does work very well.

Comment: It's not MySQL's fault. The term `CHARACTER SET` comes from earlier SQL standardisation work (eg it is present in SQL92, though not in the same context). This comes from the days when `latin1` et al were really character sets in their own right, before the Unicode standard recast them as encodings of one uber-character-set.

Comment: Thank you Bobince. That is actually an important bit of history to know for those of use who try to understand what we are coding, and not just simply "how".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL documentation includes a detailed discussion of how they use the terms *character set* and *encoding*.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-general.html